# How to mount azure file share to existing directory on linux vm

Tags: azure, shell, ubuntu, mount, mount-point

I have an existing directory on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS virtual machine at `/etc/elasticsearch`.  I also have created a file share in azure.  I am able to mount file share to the VM successfully when the mount point is a new directory.  However, when I attempt to mount the file share to `/etc/elasticsearch`, an existing directory that contains data, the existing directory's data gets overwritten completely by the contents of the file share.  This causes me to lose the data that previously existed in `/etc/elasticsearch`, which I obviously do not want.  I want the file share to be added in addition to the existing data in `/etc/elasticsearch`.

Here is what I tried:

```
if [ ! -d "/etc/smbcredentials" ]; then
sudo mkdir /etc/smbcredentials
fi
if [ ! -f "/etc/smbcredentials/credentials.cred" ]; then
sudo bash -c 'echo "username=username" >> /etc/smbcredentials/credentials.cred'
sudo bash -c 'echo "password=password" >> /etc/smbcredentials/credentials.cred'
fi
sudo chmod 600 /etc/smbcredentials/credentials.cred

sudo bash -c 'echo "//pathtofileshare/analysis /etc/elasticsearch cifs nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/credentials.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino" >> /etc/fstab'
sudo mount -t cifs //pathtofileshare/analysis /etc/elasticsearch -o vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/credentials.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

[Link to file share documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux)

Many thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is an issue, it just how Linux mount works

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html

`The previous contents (if any) and owner and mode of dir become invisible, and as long as this filesystem remains mounted, the pathname dir refers to the root of the filesystem on device.`

Comment: oh that makes sense then. do you know of a way to mount to an existing directory without its contents becoming invisible?

Comment: Nope, it's by design.

Comment: symlink is what I was looking for. it'll watch the mount directory

Comment: Thought you were looking for merging content. Link to New folder/directory will just be added inside existing folder/directory. But, yes old content will be visible.